# QGIS: Is it possible to edit the datasource of a PostGIS layer?

Tags: postgis, open-source-gis, qgis

After creating a layer with RT_SQL_Layer plugin, I want to change some details in the query. Is this possible, or do I need to create a new layer every time I want to change something in the query?

More specifically; I want to change the "Source for This Layer" as shown in example bellow:

[image]

Comment: This plugin is now deprecated. See https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/rt_sql_layer/. Now after connecting to the PostGIS database and selecting the table to add into the project, press 'Set Filter'. A new window opens up where you can select what subset of the data you wish to bring into the project. This has to be done each time if you want the PostGIS layer to show different data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot change the query used in RT SQL Layer plugin. But you can try to only use a general query in RT and refine it in Layer Properties - General - Query builder. The part in Query builder can be easily adjusted while working with the same layer.

Comment: Thats one solution. But for the given example, where the purpose of the query is to create a 3 line label the problem persists. Do you know if it can be changed with python?

Answer (score 7):

**EDIT: This is not ideal but it should work if you don't need to do it in the UI.  You can open and edit the qgs project files as the connection strings and sql string is stored in there.  When using postgres search for `<datasource>` in the qgs project file.  As the file is xml you can just edit the string and reload the project file.**

via Python:

You can kind of get half way there using the python APIs although you need to set the layers providers datasource and also the datasource on the layer itself, which you can't do......yet.

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QString
qgis.console.clearConsole()
layer = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().currentLayer()
pro = layer.dataProvider()
print "The old providers datasource"
pro.dataSourceUri()
print "Set the providers datasource"
pro.setDataSourceUri(QString(u'dbname=\'postgis\' host=localhost port=5432 user=\'postgres\' key=\'property_no\' table="(SELECT \\"t_0\\".\\"property_no\\", \\"t_0\\".\\"SP_GEOMETRY\\" FROM \\"public\\".\\"Property\\" AS \\"t_0\\"\n)" (SP_GEOMETRY) sql='))
print "Print out the new datasource"
pro.dataSourceUri()

print("Reloading data")
pro.reloadData()  
layer.reload()

print "The layers datasource"
layer.publicSource()
print "God dam! It's still the old one"
```

It seems from the code there are two places where there is a datasource string; in the provider and in the layer.  The layers datasource is not sync to the providers datasource, so you can update the provider but the layer still knows nothing.

I'll have a  chat to the devs to see if there is a reason why we couldn't sync the two together.

Comment: Thank you, at this point is maybe an workaround (with some restrictions) would be to copy the original layer datasource string, modify it, delete the old layer and create a new one...

Comment: So it looks like the postgres data provider (or any of them for that matter) doesn't implement the reloadData method from its base object, which is why the URI never makes it's way to the layer above.

Answer (score 4):

The quickest way is to open your QGIS project file (`.qgs`) in your favorite text editor (e.g., Notepad.exe, vim, whatever), and do a text search-replace for the connection string fragment.

For example, in Notepad.exe, go to Edit > Replace ...
[image: Text replace]

Answer (score 2):

The "Change DataSource Plugin" is for you :

> **ChangeDataSource**
>
> Right click on layer tree to change single layer datasource of click
>   on icon to change datasources globally
>
> The plugin allows to change the datasources of the loaded layers. The
>   operation can be performed right clicking on legend items for single
>   layer or globally on a summary table by clicking on toolbar plugin
>   icon. The plugin takes control of bad layers handling allowing to
>   specify valid datasources working on project

Works with a right click on the layer :

[image: change data source]

You will have this type of text box :

[image: PostGis datasource change]