# Change layer datasource in qgis project with python

Tags: qgis, python

I have different qgis project with some layer and their datasource like ../my_path/my_file.shp. 
I need to insert this shp file to a remote db. For do it i use shapefile from PGeo module and it's work fine. 
But i need change layer datasource in qgs project with dbname= , host etc  where schema_name is a name of qgis project, table_name is a layer id, and i need to maintain all layer's property. I tried to use:

```
 uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
 uri.setConnection("localhost", "5432", "mydb", "postgres", "postgres")
 uri.setDataSource(str(schema_name),str(layer.id()),'the_geom')
 layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), str(layer.id()), "postgres")
 QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
 layer.reload()
 print layer.source()
 if not layer.isValid():
    print "Layer is not valid"
 project.write(QFileInfo(str(dir)+'/'+project_name))
```

But i always got "Layer is not valid" and nothing is changed on my qgis project.
Is there another way to change layer datasource and save changes to the project? I see [this solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6157/in-qgis-is-it-possible-to-edit-the-datasource-of-a-postgis-layer) but it doesn't work for me

Comment: in uri.setDataSource(str(schema_name),str(layer.id()),'the_geom') instead of layer.id() (that is something internal to qgis, use the table name of your db.

Comment: str(layer.id()) is my table name.

Comment: are you sure? layer.id() if layer is a QgsVectorLayer return the layer name plus a random number!

Comment: yes,when i export my shp file into postgres db i do it like schema_name - my qgis project name, and table_name like internal id of layer i export.

Comment: I use this comand for export my shp file to db:
 shapefile._import_shapefile(host='localhost',port = 5432,dbname='mydb',user='postgres',password='postgres',shapefile = layer.source(),table =str(schema_name+"."+layer.id()),overwrite = 'false',encoding='UTF8')

Comment: ok I understood. Please print uri.uri() or layer.source() after creation. Eventually check permission on your table and schema for your user (well "postgres" user should have). And check validity before addingo to registry.

Comment: uri.uri() and layer.source() are the same: 
dbname='mydb' host=localhost port=5432 user='postgres' password='postgres' sslmode=disable key='gid' srid=3003 type=POLYGON table="PS_geologia"."PF_PAI_201420140612102415906" (the_geom) sql=
but the layer.isValid give me : False

Answer (score 3):

It's seem that's uri is a key sensitive, so I solved a problem with:

```
table_name = table_name.lower()
schema_name = schema_name.lower()
uri.setDataSource(schema_name,table_name,"the_geom", '', 'gid')
```

After this change layer.isValid() return true